# Eclipse RCP application debugging

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp

I have developing the Eclipse RCP plugin project.
How to speed up my RCP application debugging by opening only necessary view/s without new Eclipse debug instance launching?

Comment: I don't believe you can do this, but you can significantly increase the speed a debug new Eclipse launches by eliminating other views: Debug -> Debug Configurations -> your Eclipse Application configuration -> "Plug-ins" tab, launch with "features selected below" and cull some things.  The validate plugins button might help.

Comment: Thaks, I configured Debug already.

Answer (score 0):

You can not debug one view only, as it will need objects provided by the application context.

Inside the development environment, you can execute a "Unit Test" by creating a JUnit to test your View, and run it as a JUnit Plug-in Test.

[image]

**Details:**

One usually wants to debug an Eclipse RCP Application as a Whole, as it consists of many services and objects which can not exist in "the view class itself".

When you select your test and "Run As > JUnit Plug-in Test" this will create an Eclipse Context made of plugins needed to test, that usually are provided by the Eclipse application Itself.